# TypeError: 'HistoryIterator' object is not iterable

Tags: python, discord.py

```
for message in channel.history(limit=None):
```

TypeError: 'HistoryIterator' object is not iterable

this is the line of code for the error.
do you know of any way of fixing this error

Comment: Can you post example of channel.history ... you need to provide more of your code

Comment: What is channel.history? What does it do?

Comment: In your own words, when you write this line of code, what do you think it should do? Why do you think it should have any meaning? What do you think should be the value of `message` each time through the loop, and why? What does the documentation tell you about `channel.history`? Does it show examples that use a `for` loop?

Comment: channel history counts how messages there are in one channel then iterates over each messages which is messages one

Comment: history = channel.history(limit=None)
    for message in history:
        if message.author.name == ctx.author.name:
            msg_list.append(message)
    value3 = msg_list.split('\n')

Comment: Please include relevant details in the future. Just looking at your original question, there is no way to know what library you're working with, but I happen to recognize discord.py. If it isn't discord.py, please edit your question to include what it actually is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

`TextChannel.history` returns an `AsyncIterator`. You can't loop through it normally. There are two ways of doing it - you could do `await channel.history().flatten()` to first `await` it (wait for it to complete and return the value) and then `.flatten()` it into a list; however, since you set `limit = None`, this will probably be too large.

You should use the `async for` construction:

```py
async for message in channel.history(limit = None):
    pass # do something with message
```